# Polymorphism - Why Declare object variable as Base and assign Derived Class

Tags: .net, vb.net, polymorphism

***Topic:***
I try to understand polymorphism and despair of the following example (First Class is the base class and second class is the derived class):

***Code:***

```
Dim Class2 as new SecondClass()
```

is changed to

```
Dim Class2 as FirstClass
Class2 = New SecondClass()
```

***Question:***
This is according to the Author of the "VB.NET Developer Book" one of the most powerful Tool of OOP. But why? Could anyone explain that to me.

Why should I declare Class2 as FirstClass and assign this objectvariable to an instance of SecondClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: because then you could pass a SecondClass object into a function that only knew about FirstClass objects, but still get the SecondClass bevavior for methods it specialized.

Long answer: polymorphism enables us to capture the special functionality associated with different data types in a way that is highly maintainable and supports reuse. The alternative to getting that specialized logic would be for the OtherFunction to inspect the data type with an if-then, and call the appropriate method(s) on each object to get the "right" behavior for the situation:

```
if (dataObject.GetType().Name == "FirstClass")
{
    dataObject.FirstMethod();
}
else if (dataObject.GetType().Name == "SecondClass")
{
    dataObject.FirstMethod();
    dataObject.SecondMethod();
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `dataObject.GetType() == typeof(FirstClass)` to better support refactoring, code maintenance and IDE features.

Comment: Uhh... that was the alternative to polymorphism, meant to illustrate what NOT to do... do I really want to dress it up? Isn't it still a pig?

Answer (score 0):

The example with the variable is not the best one to understand this concept. Polymorphism is powerful because it allows you to create an algorithm that is bound to a general form (the BaseClass) while being able to run on any object that is derived of this form. 
Think of an algorithm that sorts integers. An important step when sorting items is to compare them. You can implement this in a way that you make a specific implementation for integers. This algorithm will only work with integers and nothing else.

```
Public Function Sort(l As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Integer)
```

But if you define the algorithm in a way that it can run on any object that can compare itself to another one of the same type, the algorithm is much more versatile and can easily be reduced. In this case you define an interface e.g. IComparable and let the algorithm work an this Interface instead. Then you can use the algorithm to sort any collection of an object that implements IComparable.

```
Public Function Sort(l As List(Of IComparable)) As List(Of Integer)
```